# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'int' and 'instance'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't know how to ask exactely but here is my code:

```
class Bruch:

    def __init__ (self,zaehler,nenner):
        self.__zaehler=zaehler
        self.__nenner=nenner

    def __mul__ (self, other):
        self.___zaehler *= other
        self.__nenner *= other

    def mal (self,other):
        self.__zaehler *= other
        self.__nenner *= other

    def __str__(self):
        return "Bruch : " + (self.__zaehler) + "/" + str(self.__nenner)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bruch1 = Bruch(2,3)
    bruch2 = Bruch(4,5)
    bruchMul = bruch1.mal(bruch2)
    print bruchMul
    bruchMul2 = bruch1*bruch2
    print bruchMul2
```

when i run it, the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'int' and 'instance'

appears.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: `+ (self.__zaehler)` => `+ str(self.__zaehler)`

Answer (score 3):

Change the function:

```
def __mul__ (self, other):
    self.__zaehler *= other
    self.__nenner *= other
```

to:

```
def __mul__ (self, other):
    return Bruch(self.__zaehler * other.__zeahler, self.__nenner * other.__nenner)
```

You want to return a new Bruch and not change the current one.

Comment: it prints None None

Comment: @VincentBeltman That wouldn't work because the __mul__ realy returns none before the edit-